# Multiple worker processes on Azure

Tags: .net, cloud, azure

Is it possible to have multiple worker processes on Azure or do I need to create a separate thread for each to get that behavior?

If Azure currently does not support this, are there plans to add this in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's clarify here: there are roles, and there are role instances.  I believe Zippy's pointing out that during the CTP, you can have at most two INSTANCES of each role.  However, you can have up to five different roles.  (This is a change starting at the July CTP.)  See Jim Nakashima's blog post on multiple web and worker roles: http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2009/07/20/working-with-multiple-web-and-worker-roles.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Azure allows you to have 2 worker processes during the beta. You can specify the amount in the configuration file. When Azure becomes a paying service you will probably be able to set a higher number, if you are willing to pay for it.

If you deploy the same code and configuration to both the production and the staging environment you can get up to 4 processes.